# Grunts and Henchmen that don't run away from protagonists or killers that is famous with high kill counts?

Tags: super-powers

This my first question on this website so sorry if i made any mistake in this public question.

So here a question i being searching on google, reddit and here but no avail.

As title stated why does so many Grunts or Henchmen in many games, shows or movies don't run away from a killer especially with super powers that they know is capable of kill thousands of trained and armed to teeth men in very short time unscathed and what even mind boggling is grunts/henchmen that just saw the killer killed dozens or hundreds of their fellows in a matter of seconds before they can put up any fight right in front of their eyes and they still not afraid of the killer and charge to their death. I can understand military soldiers or warriors that take their bravery and honor seriously but hired grunts and henchmen that is working with some secret evil organization...don't they should think they have better chance of survive by going desertion especially those had heard and what the killer is capable of? And even if they survive the onslaught by some miracle don't they know that the organization they worked with is most likely to be destroyed or suffering too much damage to even pay or benefit them in any shape or form?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm afraid I'm going to have to vote to close this as off-topic as it seems to be asking about existing fictional worlds, and not a fictional world that you're trying to build yourself. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and visiting the [help] to learn about the kinds of questions that are on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

**Russian discipline**

In the Soviet Army during WWII, the Russian were, generally speaking, poorly trained, poorly equipped, and generally out-maneuvered by the German Army. To counteract this, they use the one asset they did have - manpower. Lots and lots of manpower. But then they ran into a problem - why would their peasant conscripts charge at the enemy? Turns out the answer is simple: [They were afraid of getting shot by their own side.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_troops) Anyone fleeing the battlefield in the Russian Army was promptly shot by the officers for being a traitor. So the options available were pretty simple - either charge forward and possibly die or retreat and get shot in the back.

As an example of this, take the Grunt type enemy from the *Halo* franchise. They will run away from the player character (Master Chief) *unless* there's an Elite type enemy present, in which case they'll turn and fight.

Answer (score 2):

## Cost benefit analysis

Think about this from the perspective of the henchman. You're a member of a group. You are friends with the other henchmen. You work together, you party together. You know each other's wives and girlfriends. You've been to each other's houses. And now it's time for you to go into battle. You see your friend vaporized by the superhero's blaster cannon and now the superhero is aiming at you. You can either attack the superhero and face certain death or you can run away and... do what? The superhero might blast you anyway. And what do you do if you run away? Sure you'll live, but the other henchmen all know where you live and who you love. Now instead of endangering your life, you're endangering the lives of your loved ones. Also, the other members of your criminal organization know all the crimes that you've committed. If you run, they could release that information. Maybe the boss has members sign confessions to illegal acts that can be turned over to police if they ever try to leave.

If you want to give the henchmen in your story a more material reason to keep fighting, the boss could give them big life insurance policies. If you die in battle, you loved ones get more money than you would have earned if you lived to retirement.